# What is with() when creating a model object in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Usually I would use this to get the data using the model...

```
$site = new Site();
$sites = $site->getAll();
```

I never really liked this way... I am getting plural "sites" so always hated using singular $site->getAll(); Been looking for a better way to do it or either rename models and things.

Anyway, I stumbled on this, using with() to declare the Site, and getAll on that:

```
$sites = with(new Site)->getAll();
```

I have never seen "with" before. I have tried searching Google, StackExchange, PHP.net, and cant find anything for it (not sure if Google would exclude the word "with"!).

So I wondered, what is **with**, what does it do? Its seems nicer, shorter, allows me to not use a singular variable $site for an object I want to use to get multiple sites!

Thanks

Comment: I'd suspect it's a [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) that returns an object

Comment: looks like `with` is the identity operation, it simply returns its argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found in \Illuminate\Support\Helpers.php

```
if ( ! function_exists('with'))
{
    /**
     * Return the given object. Useful for chaining.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $object
     * @return mixed
     */
    function with($object)
    {
        return $object;
    }
}
```

The docblock comment pretty much sums up its purpose

Comment: Ahhh, there you go! Now it makes sense!! Didn't know if it was PHP or Laravel. Thanks.